# Export to CSV missing first record, using C# function

Tags: c#, function, csv, export-to-csv

Trying to export to CSV, everything works, however, the top row is missing on all exports. This row is not missing when exporting the same record to Excel or KML.

Tried re-writing the function and adding a line, but nothing works

```
public FileResult ExportToCSV()
    {
       List<Tuple<String, String>> nameValues = new    
       List<Tuple<string, string>>();
       if (ReportSession.FilterKeys != null)
    {
       nameValues = (List<Tuple<String, String>>)  
       ReportSession.FilterKeys;
    }


       ReportRequestFilter dbr = (ReportRequestFilter)     
       ReportSession.DatabaseRequestFilter;


    List<Report_Packet_History> dplist = GetAllReportData 
    (dbr.Group_Id, dbr.AllowChildgroups, dbr.Device_Id, dbr.user_id,  
    MapLimitConstants.MAX_EXPORT_BULK_ROWS, dbr.Lookback, dbr.periodEnd, 1, 
    dbr.ShowActiveOnly);
    List<Report_Packet_History> dplistreturn = GetFilters(nameValues,  
    dplist);


    //SetReportViewBags(dplist);

    DateTime endDate = dplist.Max(dt => dt.gps_datetime);
    DateTime startDate = dplist.Min(dt => dt.gps_datetime);
    String[] Device = dplist.Select(dt => dt.imei).Distinct().ToArray();
    String[] Group = dplist.Select(dt => dt.user_group_name).Distinct   
    ().ToArray();

    Utility.LocalisedDateTime ldt = ToolBox.ConvertToUserTimezone 
    (DateTime.UtcNow, Session.CurrentUserSettings.time_zone, false,  
    Session.CurrentUserSettings.Locale);


    String fileName = "IRISReport_" + string.Format("{0}_to_{1}",   
    startDate.ToShortDateString(), endDate.ToShortDateString());
    fileName += string.Format(Device.Count() > 1 ? "_Assets_" : "_Asset_"  
     +  
    Device[0]);
    fileName += string.Format(Group.Count() > 0 ? "_Groups_" : "_Group_"    
    +  Group[0]);


    //List<Report_Packet_History> dplistres = GetFilters(nameValues,  
    dplist).Take(MapLimitConstants.MAX_EXPORT_CSV_ROWS).Skip  
    (0).ToList<Report_Packet_History>();

    //Response.Charset = "";

    return GenerateCSV(dplistreturn, fileName + ".csv");

    }
```

Here is the GenerateCSV method, where would the header be set to false? I have the first row = true.

```
private FileResult GenerateCSV(List<Report_Packet_History> report, String   
        FileName)
                {
                 Type rphType = typeof  
                 (Connector.Models.Report.Report_Packet_History);
                  PropertyInfo[] myField = 
                      rphType.GetProperties().ToArray();

                  Boolean firstRow = true;
                  StringBuilder csvOut = new StringBuilder();

                  MemoryTributary stream = new MemoryTributary();
                  foreach (Report_Packet_History rph in report)
                  {
                      for (int i = 0; i < myField.Length; i++)
                       {
                            if (firstRow)
                            {
                                csvOut.Append(myField[i].Name + ",");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (myField[i].GetValue(rph) == null)
                                {
                                    csvOut. Append("" + ",");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    csvOut.Append(myField[i].GetValue  
                                    (rph).ToString() + ",");
                                 }
                              }
                         }
                         csvOut.Append("\r\n");
                         byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes    
                                         (csvOut.ToString());
                         csvOut.Clear();

            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            firstRow = false;
        }

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return File 
                  (stream,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, 
                   FileName);
    }
```

Comment: Where's the code for `Generate CSV()`??  The error is likely to be within that.

Comment: please see above

Comment: There are a ton of CSV libraries, including ADO.NET. Why are you reinventing the wheel here?

Comment: What is the value of `report[0]` if you debug it at the start of the `foreach` loop in the `GenerateCSV`?  Is it your first full row, or is it the second?  That said, I agree with several others here that you should be using the inherent libraries instead of reinventing CSV processing ground-up.

Answer (score 0):

First row is supposed to be Headers row and I guess that somewhere in your GenerateCSV method you have write header set to false.

Comment: please see above

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the first row of date, in lieu of writing your header.

When you start your loop using `i`, it is zero.  Your first row flag is also true.
The first iteration sees the first row flag and writes the header, then resets the flag.  That's OK.
However, the code then loops to the next iteration, which is the SECOND line of data.

You need to write the header out first, THEN start looping through your data.

And for an improvement all round, look into `File.WriteAllLines()` ;)

Comment: How do I seperate the header from looping through the rest of the data?

Comment: Just pull out your first record, iterate the Fields to get the headers, and write the headers.  Then start your iteration of the data (your existing loops) but without the first row logic.

Comment: Or to put it another way, pull the first row section of logic out so that it's before your loops.

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned above and it works but not quite as we would like. Would there be anyway of just addding a extra row in somewhere to account for the header?

Comment: I don't understand.  What's not quite as you would like?  You can easily add any extra row in - just write out a carriage return.